# Programa em C crashando quando executa

Tags: c, string, memória

Assim que insiro os dados da variável `originalMoney` o *prompt crasha*.

Segue o código (está incompleto, só efetuei o teste com o primeiro `case`)

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float coinsValue, notesValue, totalMoney;
    int switchValue;
    char originalMoney, convertedMoney;

    printf("Enter original money type\n");
    scanf("%c",&originalMoney);

    printf("Enter the type of money you want to convert\n");
    scanf("%c",&convertedMoney);

    if (strcmp(originalMoney, "REAL") == 0 && strcmp(convertedMoney, "DOLLAR") == 0){
        switchValue = 1;
    } else if (strcmp(originalMoney, "REAL") == 0 && strcmp(convertedMoney, "LIBRAS")){
        switchValue = 2;
    } else if (strcmp(originalMoney, "DOLLAR") == 0 && strcmp(convertedMoney, "REAL")){
        switchValue = 3;
    } else if (strcmp(originalMoney, "DOLLAR") == 0 && strcmp(convertedMoney, "LIBRAS")){
        switchValue = 4;
    } else if (strcmp(originalMoney, "LIBRAS") == 0 && strcmp(convertedMoney, "REAL")){
        switchValue = 5;
    } else if (strcmp(originalMoney, "LIBRAS") == 0 && strcmp(convertedMoney, "DOLLAR")){
        switchValue = 6;
    } else {
        printf("You have chosen an invalid conversion option!");
    }

    switch (switchValue) {
    case 1:
        printf("Entering case 1...\n");

        printf("Enter coins value in R$: \n");
        scanf("%f",coinsValue);

        printf("Enter notes value in R$: \n");
        scanf("%f",notesValue);

        totalMoney = coinsValue + notesValue;
        totalMoney = totalMoney * 4.01;

        printf("The value in reais converted to dollar is: %.2f",totalMoney);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Entering case 2...\n");
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Entering case 3...\n");
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Entering case 4...\n");
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("Entering case 5...\n");
        break;
    case 6:
        printf("Entering case 6...\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problema é que você está tentando colocar uma string em um único caracter, isso nunca vai funcionar em C

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está declarando `originalMoney` e `convertedMoney` como `char`, portanto tem um espaço de 1 byte reservado em cada. Aí você tenta por vários bytes nela, isto corrompe a memória e dá erro. O que você provavelmente queria fazer era declara uma *string*, ou como é em C, um *array* de `char`. E aí mandar ler como *string*, algo assim:

```
char originalMoney[10];
scanf("%s9", &originalMoney);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/RightAllocation.c).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @PedroGuilherme veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.